# Debian wheezy FN key inverted after resume from suspend

Tags: linux, keyboard, debian, suspend

I have debian wheezy installed on my new laptop (Toshiba Satellite L70), with Kernel 3.14 from backports.

After I resume from suspend, all function keys (<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd>) behaviour is inverted, for example, instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to close a window, I have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>. Function keys alone perform special operations (volume up/down, brightness, etc.).
 A restart brings things back to normal.

Comment: Is there a FnLock or NumLock key enabled somewhere? Are you using multiple keyboards?

Comment: There is no FnLock key, Enabling/disabling NumLock does not affect the behaviour. I am using only the laptop keyboard.